# vCeter API for Monitoring the Inventory

Tags: vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I am trying to get the monitoring details for virtual machines in vCenter? I was not able to find any Rest API's. I am looking for a kind of CloudWatch(EC2) for vCenter.

Answer (score 0):

The REST API of vCenter doesn't currently have the ability to pull performance metrics. You'll have to reference the web services (SOAP) API instead: https://code.vmware.com/apis/358/vsphere